# How to create string in loop in x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I have a string, and I want to convert any symbol in that string to another (as an example, and "a" to "4", and "e" to "3" etc.).

Logic:

i) string variable defined using `db`

ii) string variable defined using `resb` to transfer the converted characters to

iii) loop through first string and use `cmp` to convert the characters as required

iv) while looping store converted characters in the second variable

v) print second converted string

My current attempt:

```
section .data
    ; constants
    EXIT_SUCCESS    equ 0
    SYS_exit    equ 60
    SYS_read    equ 0
    SYS_write   equ 1

    ; variables
    sym     db "01010",10,"$"
    text0   db " "
    text1   db "$"
    text2   db "",10
    
section .bss
    ; reserve space for output symbol
    symbol  resb 6

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, sym
    call _print

    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall


_print:
    mov rbx, 0          ; use rbx to count len(string)

_printLoop:
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]       ; will hold next char in string
    
    cmp cl, "0"         ; if 0 add space
    je _addT0

    cmp cl, "1"         ; if 1 add $ symbol
    je _addT1

    cmp cl, "$"         ; if end of string
    je _continuePrint

    mov symbol[rbx], text3      ; default: add new line 
    jmp _printLoop

_addT0:
    mov symbol[rbx], text0
    jmp _printLoop

_addT1:
    mov symbol[rbx], text1
    jmp _printLoop

_continuePrint:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, symbol
    mov rdx, rbx            ; use rbx as count
    syscall

    ret
```

As an example, if `sym` is `"01010"`, I would expect an output `sym` equal to `" $ $ "`.

Comment: `mov symbol[rbx], text0` copies the address not the value.

Comment: Incrementing `rax` at `_printLoop:` makes you to always omit the first character of input string. Instead of `text0   db " "` use `text0 equ " "`; similary `text1 equ "$"`, `text2 equ 10`. Correct NASM syntax is then `mov byte [symbol+rbx], text2 ; default: add new line`.

Comment: @vitsoft thanks, how would I go about not omitting the first character of the input string? please consider making your comment the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing `rax` at `_printLoop:` makes you to always omit the first character of input string. Postpone the incrementation to later, after the address from `eax` has been used:

```
_printLoop:
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]       ; will hold next char in string
    inc rax             ; Prepare EAX to point at the next character.
    ...
```

The instruction like `mov symbol[rbx], text0` are wrong, because `text0` represents **address** of `text0`, not its **contents**.
Redefine  `text0   db " "` to `text0 equ " "`, this will make it a **value** (immediate number `" "` alias 0x20) instead of **memory variable**. Similary `text1 equ "$"`, and `text2 equ 10`.
Correct NASM syntax is then
`mov byte [symbol+rbx], text2 ; default: add new line.`

Comment: Thank you so much - super helpful. Can I ask why it is `[symbol+rbx]`? Or is that just the syntax needed?

Comment: @Dean Square brackets `[]` make the difference between **[memory_contents]** and **immediate_value** in most assemblers. See also [memory address syntax](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#RegisterExpressions).